# General equation of a circle from chord

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

Is there a general equation for a circle with a given chord (and other minimum necessary conditions). In quite a lot of questions, the chord length/equation of chord is given and that of circle is asked. I know there must be minimum three conditions to define a unique circle and a chord might just be two of them but given the length and equation of chord how do I find the coordinates of the end points. More precisely, how do I find the end points of a chord given the equation of circle and chord without actually having to solve them simultaneously, i.e. some quirk from the properties of circles/chords box.

Ps; might sound too vague but bear with me here.

Comment: Given the equation of the chord and its length, you cannot find the endpoints. Given the equation of the circle and the chord, the only way to find the endpoints is by solving simultaneously. There may be specific geometries that simplify that, but in general, there is no royal road to the endpoints.

Comment: You’re asking two related, but different questions here. First you ask how to find a circle given an equation of (the extension of) a chord and the chord length, which as @NickD explained, isn’t enough information. Then you ask how to find the endpoints of a chord given a circle and a line. That’s a rather different computation that comes down to an application of the Pythagorean theorem.